Notion Database IDs Undefined in AWS Amplify Production Environment Despite Correct Environment Variables
I'm using AWS Amplify for my Next.js app and trying to integrate with the Notion API. In my local development environment, everything works fine, and the Notion database IDs are correctly accessed via environment variables. However, in my production deployment on AWS Amplify, the environment variables for the Notion database IDs (e.g., NEXT_NOTION_MARKETING_DATABASE_ID) are showing as undefined.
Here is my relevant coudwatch log:
Error adding to Notion database: Error: NOTION_MARKETING_DATABASE_ID environment variable is missing.
Here is my relevant client-side code:
const handleSubscription = async () => {
    if (!userOrg && !userLocation) {
      handleIPRequest().catch((e) => {
        e;
      });
    }

    if (!subscriptionEmail) {
      alert("Please enter a valid email");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const emailData: Record<string, string> = {
        email: subscriptionEmail,
      };

      if (userOrg) {
        emailData.organization = userOrg;
        if (userLocation) {
          emailData.location = userLocation;
        }
      }

      const endpointUrl = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_URL_PREFIX}/api/addSubscription`;
      if (!endpointUrl) {
        console.error(
          "Environment variable NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_URL_PREFIX is missing.",
        );
        alert("Internal error. Please try again later.");
        return;
      }

      const emailResponse = await axios.post(endpointUrl, emailData);

      // Safeguard for missing status or malformed response
      if (emailResponse.status === 200) {
        console.log("Subscribed successfully:", emailResponse.data);
        setOpenAlert(true);
        setSubscriptionEmail(""); // Clear the email input field

        // Automatically close the alert after 7 seconds
        setTimeout(() => {
          setOpenAlert(false);
        }, 7000);
      } else {
        alert("Failed to subscribe. Please try again.");
        console.error(
          "Unexpected response:",
          emailResponse.status,
          emailResponse.data,
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        console.error("Subscription error:", error.message);
      } else {
        console.error("An unknown error occurred");
      }

      alert("An error occurred. Please try again later.");
    }
  };

Here is my server-side code:
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client";
import "dotenv/config";

// Initialize the Notion client with your integration token
const notion = new Client({ auth: process.env.NEXT_NOTION_API_TOKEN });

console.log(
  process.env.NEXT_NOTION_MARKETING_DATABASE_ID,
  process.env.NEXT_NOTION_BUSINESS_DATABASE_ID,
);

export async function POST(req) {
  try {
    // Parse the request body
    const body = await req.json();
    const email = body.email ?? null;
    const organization = body.organization ?? "";
    const location = body.location ?? "";

    if (!email) {
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Email is required" }), {
        status: 400,
      });
    }

    // Get the current date in ISO 8601 format
    const date = new Date().toISOString();

    // Choose the correct Notion database based on the presence of `organization`
    let databaseId;
    if (organization) {
      if (process.env.NEXT_NOTION_BUSINESS_DATABASE_ID) {
        const businessID = process.env.NEXT_NOTION_BUSINESS_DATABASE_ID;

        if (!businessID) {
          throw new Error(
            "NOTION_BUSINESS_DATABASE_ID environment variable is missing.",
          );
        }

        databaseId = process.env.NEXT_NOTION_BUSINESS_DATABASE_ID;
      }
    } else {
      const marketingID = process.env.NEXT_NOTION_MARKETING_DATABASE_ID;

      if (!marketingID) {
        throw new Error(
          "NOTION_MARKETING_DATABASE_ID environment variable is missing.",
        );
      }

      databaseId = process.env.NEXT_NOTION_MARKETING_DATABASE_ID;
    }

    console.log("Using Database ID:", databaseId);

    // Add a new entry (page) to the Notion database
    const notionResponse = await notion.pages.create({
      parent: { database_id: databaseId },
      properties: {
        // "Name" is the title property, this is required in Notion
        Name: {
          title: [
            {
              text: {
                content: email, // Using email as the title for this example
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        // The "Email" field as a string (email type)
        Email: {
          email: email, // Ensure email is passed as a plain string
        },
        // Add the "Location" field as a rich_text property
        Location: {
          rich_text: [
            {
              text: {
                content: location,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        // Add the "Date" field as a date property
        Date: {
          date: {
            start: date, // Ensure the date is in ISO 8601 format
          },
        },
      },
    });

    // Return a success response
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ message: "Data added successfully", notionResponse }),
      {
        status: 200,
      },
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error adding to Notion database:", error);
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ message: "Error subscribing", error }),
      {
        status: 500,
      },
    );
  }
}

Here's what I've done so far:
I have correctly defined the environment variables in the Amplify console under App settings > Environment variables.
I’ve redeployed the app after adding/updating the environment variables.
I’ve checked CloudWatch logs, which show that the variables are missing, even though they are defined in the Amplify environment.
I’ve tried logging the variables in the code, and they are still undefined in production.
const marketingDatabaseId = process.env.NEXT_NOTION_MARKETING_DATABASE_ID;
I've double-checked the environment settings for the correct environment (production).
I've confirmed that the environment variable names are correct and case-sensitive.
This issue seems specific to the production environment, as the variables work fine in local development.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#access-ssr-environment-variables

i have same problem but you can try to edit amplify.yml in build settings, for example if you use npm


version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - echo "NEXT_NOTION_MARKETING_DATABASE_ID=$NEXT_NOTION_MARKETING_DATABASE_ID" >> .env
        - echo "NEXT_NOTION_BUSINESS_DATABASE_ID=$NEXT_NOTION_BUSINESS_DATABASE_ID" >> .env
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
      - .next/cache/**/*



this works like a charm, and you can try the docs from aws amplify environtment
